# Graphical Lasso for estimating words network

Tags: lasso, graphical-model, precision-matrix

I have a matrix whose columns are words and rows are different speeches by a person. Therefore, the i,j element of the matrix is the count of occurence of a word in a speech. I would like to estimate a network out of this, to see the association of words. I wanted to use the graphical lasso to estimate the precision matrix (which gives me the associations), however these are count data, is the approach still valid?